# Paging on Posts of a Blog like SO in MVC 3 Razor and EntityFramework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am working with MVC 3, Razor and Entity Framework. I am making a blog using MVC 3, so on the blog there are many posts. On the homepage I am showing for now say 10 posts.

I am using the following code to display posts.

```
 <h1 class="postTitle">@Html.ActionLink(post.PostTitle, "SinglePost", "Post", new { postID = post.PostID}, null)</h1>

 <div class="postDateTime"><b>Posted on :</b> @post.PostDateTime</div>
 <br/>
 @if(post.PostContent.Length > 500)
 {
     <span>@post.PostContent.Substring(0, 500) [Read More...]</span>
 }
 else
 {
     <span>@post.PostContent</span>
 }

 <hr class="postSeparator"/>
 </div>
```

I am a little confused as to how to implement paging for this, or better something like this implemented  at SO.
Please guide me on this fellas.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key point is to use Skip() and Take() LINQ methods when querying your model:

EG

```
int page;
int pageSize;
var postsToDisplay =db.Posts.Where(x => x.Tag == "EF")
                            .Skip((page -1) * pageSize)
                            .Take(pageSize);
```

You should place this in a ViewModel, and then use View which is strongly typed to your  ViewModel.

Comment: found this http://afana.me/post/paging-sorting-and-searching-ef-cf-and-mvc.aspx, neatly explained !

Comment: forgot to add '* pagesize'. Just updated. From your link note that the controller could also take a parameter for pageSize with a default value set as with 'page'. PageSize is often saved to a cookie in webapps.

Comment: for people that gonna read this later on here is one more nice article at http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=618

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like [PagedList](https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList)

Check out the Readme, it has a good example of what you're trying to do. It's also available on [Nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/PagedList)

Once you get paging working, you can style the pager to look like SO.